# How to select only a div from another page with AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a Social Media with posts, and I want to show the new with JS and AJAX. I tried to reload my page with AJAX and put it in a div element, but now the website is in this div element, so I have the full page twice. However, I only want to take the div element with AJAX. My code looks like this:

```js
var timeout = setTimeout(loadDoc, 2000);

function loadDoc() {
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "mywebsite.com");
  xhttp.send();
  timeout = setTimeout(loadDoc, 2000);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
post2<br>
post1
</div>
```

Can someone help me?

Kind regards, ComputerJoshi

Comment: Prefer the use of [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) over `XMLHttpRequest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches you can take here:

## Have a sensible API design

The URL you are requesting is returning a bunch of data you don't want.

Change it (or create a new URL to request instead) so that you only get the data you want.

You *could* keep that data in HTML form, but it is more typical to present it in a structured format (JSON is popular) and then use that to update the DOM of the current page.

## Parse the HTML

Convert the string of HTML into a DOM (e.g. with [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)), then use `querySelector` to find the parts of that DOM you want and then copy them into the current DOM.